# Haskell-like range in PureScript?

Tags: purescript

Is there a native function that behaves like Haskell's range?

I found out that `2..1` returns a list `[2, 1]` in PureScript, unlike Haskell's `[2..1]` returning an empty list `[]`. After Googling around, I found the behavior is written in the [Differences from Haskell](https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/language/Differences-from-Haskell.md#where-is--from-haskell) documentation, but it doesn't give a rationale behind.

In my opinion, this behavior is somewhat inconvenient/unintuitive since `0 .. (len - 1)` doesn't give an empty list when `len` is zero, and this could possibly lead to cryptic bugs.

1. Is there a way to obtain the expected array (i.e. range of length `len` incrementing from 0) without handling the `length == 0` case every time?
2. Also, why did PureScript decide to make range behave like that?

P.S. How I ran into this question: I wanted to write a `getLocalStorageKeys` function, which gets all keys from the local storage. My implementation gets the number of keys using the [length](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-web-storage/3.0.0/docs/Web.Storage.Storage#v:length) function, creates a range from 0 to `numKeys - 1`, and then traverses it with the [key](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-web-storage/3.0.0/docs/Web.Storage.Storage#v:key) function. However, the range didn't behave as I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just make it yourself?

```
indicies :: Int -> Array Int
indicies n = if n <= 0 then [] else 0..(n-1)
```

As far as "why", I can only speculate, and my speculation is that the idea was to avoid this kind of `if`fy logic for creating "reverse" ranges - which is something that does come up for me in Haskell once in a while.

Comment: I think I should go for this. What case did you have to create if-fy logic for reverse ranges? Was that a common situation?

Comment: It's the case where I need such list in reverse order. Not terribly common, by any means.